# visual basic for applications classes Compile error: Expected: end of Statement

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I am trying to rewrite some C++ into an excel macro, but can't seem to even get line 1 of any tutorial on classes in VBA to work.

I have tried the following:

```
Public Class gamepath
End Class

Sub Whatever()  
End Sub
```

Then, when I run the `Whatever()` Macro I expect it to compile but I get the error:

```
Compile error: 
Expected: end of Statement
```

And it highlights the word `gamepath`

I am not skilled enough in VB to know why this error occurs, and the error is too vague for my searches to pull up anything I can use.  Can anyone tell me why this won't compile?

Comment: This is FYI so you know... VB is different from VBA.  VBA is almost always limited to MS Office products and working with automation between the products (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc). VB these days is also referred to as  .NET and is a more general use language. If you're working in VBA, look over [this reference](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) for a good grounding in classes.

Comment: Good catch on my misunderstanding! I definitely just thought VBA and VB were the same thing.  I'll add that to the list of things I've learned today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you're using looks like it's vb.net, not VBA. The syntax is similar, but not the same. In VBA, you don't script a class, you insert a special type of code module that contains the class's code. `Sub Whatever` resides in that.

Insert a class module, name it "GameClass" (classes are typically proper-cased, not lower-cased). Add your methods and any properties ([here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/class-modules/properties.htm) is a good overview of property getters/setters) in that module:

[image]

Then you can instantiate your `GameClass` and call its methods from elsewhere:

[image]

Comment: Yes! This has clearly answered my confusion and I can now actually work on this task.  Thank you!